# how to read flags and filenames separately in C? (based on WC utility)

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopt

let say if I have:
./some_app (flags) (text files)

where there are some number of flags to be used(like optional flags) and some number of text files to be used

some further example usage:

./some_app -l -c -w foo.txt bar.txt

./some_app -l -c -w -r foo.txt bar.txt

I already know how to process command flags but since they are sperate loops: i am suck on this part

```
for (int i = argc; i < argc; i++) //Loop over the filename arguments./some_app -c -l -w -n ex/foo.txt ex/bar.txt
{
    FILE *file_fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
    if ((file_fp == NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: No such file or directory\n", argv[i]);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
       use get opts in a switch case using getline
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = argc; i < argc; i++)` should be `for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)`

Comment: `No such file or directory` is a lie if the file exists but fopen failed because of some other issue.  Don't guess at the reason for the failure.  `if( file_fp == NULL) { perror(argv[i]); return EXIT_FAILURE;}`

Answer (score 0):

Simply process the argument differently if there is a - in front

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) //Loop over the filename arguments./some_app -c -l -w -n ex/foo.txt ex/bar.txt
{
    const char *argument = argv[i];
    if (argument[0] == '-')
    {
        Process the flag here
    }
    else
    {
        FILE *file_fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if ((file_fp == NULL))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: No such file or directory\n", argv[i]);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
           use get opts in a switch case using getline
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getopt(3)` to parse command line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "lcwr")) != EOF) {
        switch(opt) {
        case 'l': printf("option -l processed\n"); break;
        case 'c': printf("option -c processed\n"); break;
        case 'w': printf("option -w processed\n"); break;
        case 'r': printf("option -r processed\n"); break;
        }
    }
    /* shift the args */
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
    /* process the files */
    if (argc == 0) {
        printf("No arguments\n");
    } else {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            printf("Argument [%d] = \"%s\"\n",
                 i, argv[i]);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`getopt(3)` exists in almost any C implementation to allow command line processing.  Read the manual page of `getopt(3)`.